# Jquery photoswipe not working need refresh

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am setting up a jquery mobile photoswipe, but for some reason it won't start unless refresh the page.

after click on the photoswip button, I need to refresh the page tot get photoswipe start

but if I open the photoswipe page straight away, it work ok. how can I fix it please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the order of hte scripts loading.

It should load like:
jquery
jquery mobile
klass
phoneswipe

That should work...

Ps: there is a js error on the page hence the problem...

Comment: I tried that, but got nothing different. can you advice what problem with js file pls?

Comment: ... can you try move the js to the end of the file ... The error: Code.PhotoSwipe.createInstance: No images to passed.... maybe the images are not there yet but on reload they are in the cache????

Comment: have moved all js to the end, you can check the source code of the page, but still need to refresh to make the photoswipe work. anything I can do for the js file to force the page load automatically? thanks

Comment: How did you solve it i have the same problem?